# Perl codes always connecting to same MySQL database although it is configured to connect to different server

Tags: mysql, perl

Perl codes always connecting to same MySQL(local but in error showing FQDN of server) database although it is configured to connect to different server. 
please see the codes.

```
$datasetname="DBI:mysql:database=applications;host=entdb"

$$dbobject = DBI -> connect ($datasetname, $username, $password,
                           {RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0})
                  or $errflg2 = 1;
print TT ("                   : ".time()."\n");
close (TT);
if ($errflg2 > 0)
{
 $errmsg  = "ERROR opening up the database: $datasetname\n";
 $errmsg .= "  Error number: " . $DBI::err . "\n";
 $errmsg .= "  Error text  : " . $DBI::errstr . "\n";
 print "$errmsg";
 ilog ($ifile, $errmsg);
 mail_it ($errmsg);
 if ($debug != 0) { close (DB); }
 exit (1);
}
else
{ print "Opened the '" . $datasetname . "' database.\n"; }**
enter code here
```

**error
ERROR opening up the database: DBI:mysql:database=applications;host=entdb
  Error number: 1045
  Error text  : Access denied for user 'entdb'@'vpl121' (using password: YES)**

see in code i referred entdb, but Perl connecting to  VPL121. Perl codes are running on vpl121.

Comment: Your code has a few syntax errors. Are you SURE this is the real code you actually ran?

Answer (score 1):

In mysql all user accounts are identified via [username@hostname format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html),  where hostname is the host name or ip address of the computer from which the code connects to the mysql database.

You did write that the perl code runs on `vpl121`, therefore this is the hostname that mysql uses. Apparently, you do not have any user account that matches the 'entdb'@'vpl121' or the password is incorrect or the given user does not have access to the entdb database.

My guess is that you do not have any matching user accounts. Consider perhaps creating an 'entdb'@'%' user account, where % as hostname stands for any host name or ip address.

Comment: Thanks. but i am connecting to entdb server. using user name entdb.

$datasetname="DBI:mysql:database=applications;host=entdb".
not to vpl121 server. in code no where i mentioned vpl121. FYI codes are ruuning on VPL121 server.